# ng-repeat orderby of dynamic lenght of object

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following object that contains 2 fixed attributes (OrderId and Purchasedate, and an array of attribues. I try to to put this in ng-repeat with orderBy option. The first 2 attribute (OrderId and PurchaseDate) work OK when sorting is applied by clicking on the header. However I do not get it working on the 3 rd attribute and so on.

The rows shown on the table are correct.

The object looks like 
e.g.

```
$scope.orders; 
[
    { OrderId: "P888291", PurchaseDate : "2016-12-02", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "New York"}, { Name: "Street", Value: "Broadway 5" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "USA" } ] } },
{ OrderId: "P334498", PurchaseDate : "2016-11-02", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "London" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "WestMinister 3" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "Great Brittain" } ] } },
{ OrderId: "G393383", PurchaseDate : "2016-11-28", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "Milan" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "Pizza 8" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "Italy" } ] } },
{ OrderId: "P978381", PurchaseDate : "2015-05-25", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "Seattle" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "Houston 9" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "US" } ] } },
{ OrderId: "P983394", PurchaseDate : "2015-06-05", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "Amsterdam" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "Damrak 5" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "Netherlands" } ] } },
{ OrderId: "G678994", PurchaseDate : "2015-04-01", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "The Hague" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "Markt 22" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "Netherlands" } ] } },

{ OrderId: "P128994", PurchaseDate : "2016-12-04", 
     Items: { elt : [ { Name: "City", Value: "The Hague" }, { Name: "Street",  Value: "Plein 7" }, { Name: "Country", Value: "Netherlands" } ] } },
];
```

Please advise and the code is put in :

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAG7BWVK8BYH

Answer (score 0):

You can try with custom filter logic.(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy )
for example:

JS:

```
$scope.filterOrderFn = function(orderobj)
{
// Do 

if(...)
{
    return _something_// this will be your sorted order according to your first condition
}
else if(...)
{
    return _something_ // this will be your sorted order according to your second condition if require
}

return false; // otherwise it won't be within the orderlist
};
```

HTML:

```
...
 <article data-ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:filterOrderFn" class="order"> 
...
```

If you need a very specific ordering behaviour you could write your own filter (although orderBy should be enough for most uses cases). As you may know you can chain many filters together, so adding your custom filter function doesn't force you to remove the previous filter using the search object (they will work together seamlessly).